# Fade Effect Left to Right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fadein, fadeout

I'm developing an app in augmented reality with Unity3D and I want to add some effect to the augmentations.
Specifically a fade in effect but not on the entire object (in my case a Quad with a texture), I'm searching a way to do this from left to right, like a "gradient effect".
The general examples explain to do this changing the Alpha channel time by time, there is a way to do this time by time but from left to right?

There is an example of Fade effect, acting only to the Alpha channel

```
IEnumerator FadeImage(bool fadeAway)
{
    // fade from opaque to transparent
    if (fadeAway)
    {
        // loop over 1 second backwards
        for (float i = 1; i >= 0; i -= Time.deltaTime)
        {
            // set color with i as alpha
            img.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    // fade from transparent to opaque
    else
    {
        // loop over 1 second
        for (float i = 0; i <= 1; i += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            // set color with i as alpha
            img.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a custom shader for this.

Comment: As I imagined.
I was hoping to avoid to write a custom shader. Ok, thanks.